# Thread in stream vs Parallel Stream

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I am unsure about which to use in performance wise. Which should be used? Both version have the some functionality.

Code snippet 1

```
fileMap.values().stream().parallel().forEach(file -> {
    downlod(file);
});
```

Code snippet 2

```
fileMap.values().forEach(file -> {
    executor.execute(file);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using the [`parallelStream(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream()) approach since it is easy to use and has a low cognitive complexity. I would only switch to another solution if the performance of `parallelStream` is not sufficient or if a functionality is needed that cannot be replicated with `parallelStream()`.

Answer (score 1):

In case of heavy computation task, go with separate executor. `parallelStream` uses shared thread pool, thus heavy tasks can potentially block `parallelStreams` in other parts of application.